# looking to upgrade php 5.4 to php 5.5 or greater on centos7

Tags: php, centos7, php5, upgrade, php7

New to this, so please bear with me.

Reviewed the php stats of the server, with `yum list installed` :

```
php.x86_64                              5.4.16-42.el7                  @base
php-cli.x86_64                          5.4.16-42.el7                  @base
php-common.x86_64                       5.4.16-42.el7                  @base
php-devel.x86_64                        5.4.16-42.el7                  @base
php-mysql.x86_64                        5.4.16-42.el7                  @base
php-pdo.x86_64                          5.4.16-42.el7                  @base
php-pear.noarch                         1:1.9.4-21.el7                 @base
php-process.x86_64                      5.4.16-42.el7                  @base
php-xml.x86_64                          5.4.16-42.el7                  @base
```

I was trying to figure out the repo that was used to install this, but unable to get that info. So was going to upgrade from 5.4 to 5.5 in a stage by stage process following steps as provided [WebTactic](https://webtatic.com/packages/php55/)

I ran the php version command to get this info:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Nov  6 2016 00:29:02)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

Just want to make sure I do this right and not muck things up. Yes I already took a snap shot of the server incase the install goes bad.

Can anyone advise me if the upgrade from [WebTactic](https://webtatic.com/packages/php55/) is the best path to follow? Could I skip the php55 version and jump right to [php7 at WebTactic](https://webtatic.com/packages/php70/)

**UPDATE**

Digging thru some Server Documentation found this with regards to Apache / PHP installation on the web server:

```
$ rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
$ rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
$ yum install httpd php56w php56w-opcache php56w-mysql php56w-gd
```

However when i run phpinfo() on the server via a web browser it displays:

**PHP Version 5.4.16**

**Update 2:**

OH if repo is from **WebTactic** than I guess the answer is **YES**!!!

Comment: The repo is shown right in your list `@base` - this means it's just the plain PHP that comes with CentOS. No one except you can tell you if you should upgrade to PHP7 because only you know if your code is ready for this.

Comment: Okay, but if I follow the process to upgrade on WebTactic to PHP 5.5 - are the steps provided okay for me to follow? My local copy of php is that of 5.6. I just acquired this responsibility and I want to upgrade so I can use some new functionality. Someone else set this system up and they have moved on in their career.

Comment: No one except you can decide to trust a software repository. Whatever you select, be sure has security patches applied, possibly backported to the earlier version.

Comment: I have a lot of learning to do. I'm not in my area of expertise when it comes to server administration. :( Lucky me I just coded a fix so I don't need to upgrade the server at this time.. but this is something that needs to eventually be done.